# Release configuration problem with Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: synaptic, release-management

I recently updated my Ubuntu 10 (lucid) to 14 (trusty).
Now the *synaptic package manager* refuses to start saying:

```
E: The value 'lucid' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not  available in the sources
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

I tried to find such a reference in `/etc`, `/var` and my *home folder*, but found none fixing the problem.

Does anyone can help?

**EDIT**: I want to make clear I already searched the most obvious configuration files like `/etc/apt/source.list` and *Ubuntu software center* works correctly (even if apt based too).

Anyway, here is the apt source.list:

```
 # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140416.2)]/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse restricted universe  #Added by software-properties
 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty restricted main
 deb-src http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse universe restricted main #Added by software-properties

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse

 deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
 deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe multiverse

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty restricted

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
 deb-src http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse universe restricted main #Added by software-properties

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
 deb-src http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
 deb-src http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse universe restricted main #Added by software-properties
 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
 deb http://ftp.free.org/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

 deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
 deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Comment: Please, edit your question by displaying the output of this file: `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @ begueradj:Well, thanks, but I think the problem is not so easy to fix :-)

Answer (score 0):

I read again the error you have got. This lead me to read again your question.
It is useless to try to resolve your problem because as soon as you fix it (I wonder if it is really possible), you will encounter several other problems that could *never* be solved. But why ?
The reason is simple: You can upgrade Ubuntu only to the next version which follows it in the hierarchy of Ubuntu releases. For example: **you can upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 only if you are running Ubuntu 13.10.**
You did not precise the version of Ubuntu you are running (10.04 or 10.10). So it will be a long process for you to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 because you must upgrade following this schema:

1. Upgrade Ubuntu 10.04  to Ubuntu 12.04
2. Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04  to Ubuntu 12.10
3. Upgrade Ubuntu 12.10  to Ubuntu 13.04
4. Upgrade Ubuntu 13.04  to Ubuntu 13.10
5. Upgrade Ubuntu 13.04  to Ubuntu 14.04

You will find more details on this official [document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes).

Comment: I wonder how you did. Anyway, I hope you won't have troubles with it later.

Comment: Actually, I upgraded from U-10 using the U-14 (gnome-shell) installation disk. When selecting "Install", the installer detects an older U version and suggests to update, warning some things (and particularly system settings) will be erased. And this works rather well. The installer fails to repack a lot of software, but it's not a real problem, and synaptic is the only problem I have.Anyway, I read somewhere else what you say, but all this is rather inconsistent. So, thanks for you reply, but I will wait a little to see if someone has another idea.

Comment: @user299476 This is not upgrading: it is installation :)

Comment: @ begueradj: Yes, if you want. And I reinstalled the synaptic package manager from U Software too. I'm not using a former version, but I suspect some part of the older version blocks the way (cache ? I didn't dare to clear the little dbs hidden in /var)

Comment: @user299476 During the installation process: Ubuntu 10 was erased, no ? If it is, I may set a bounty of 50 points to your question so that it will attract the attention of more experienced users that may help you.

Comment: @ begueradj : very kind of yours, but I wouldn't like to diminish your reputation :-) That said, I would say U-10 have been erased, but probably not fully. Some applications preferences (like Firefox and Eclipse) remained untouched. It was not a really clean install.

Comment: @user299476 Do not worry, I am here to learn and help, not to collect points :) I will set the bounty when I am allowed (i think a question needs 2 days of waiting before being able to set a bounty on it) I am interested in your question because what happened is strange and I do not understand it. I think you did not use a CD/DVD or USB key to install Ubuntu 14. if you rely on Ubuntu 10 to install U.14 it could explain your situation.

Comment: No I booted from an USB key created with the downloaded iso file.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the synaptic configuration file

> rm /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf in the root account.

That's where the error lies. After that synaptic should work.

You could probably  just fix the one or two value, but as the synaptic configuration obviously has gone oncoherent, I would recommand just to remove it to get a clean new one.

I had a similar problem on my system and it fixed it within seconds.